# Unable to display loading while post with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have trouble displaying a loading div when the process is being initialized. I have another bootstrap modal being displayed and after ajax request, I would want to display loader and blur the bootstrap modal and background. The issue here is that currently my loader is send to the back of the modal.

```
#loader {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 175px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 175px;
    position:relative;
}
#loader {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 175px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 175px;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader" style='display:none'>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="lading"></div>
</div>
<div id="reg-form" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
</div
</div>
```

```js
$('form#register-form').submit(function(e) {
    var formInfo = {};
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";

    $.post("ajax_handler/ajax_handler.php", {
        action: 'register_user',
        param: formInfo,
        pos: lastNode.id
    }, function(response, status) {  
        try {
            jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);              
        } catch(err) {
            alert("Sorry, we are not able to fulfill the request. Your query cannot be processed right now.");           
            return;
        }

        if (jsonResponse.result == false) {  
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
            alert("Sorry. " + jsonResponse.msg);
        }             

        disableGraphKey(true);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Set `z-index` property

Comment: try that, didnt work. It won't even display the loader :(

Comment: I have experience the same problem. As a workaround, I have put the jquery ajax call to a setTimeout function with the 200 ms delay. I know there are better approach but this worked for me.

Comment: Hide loader in error and success cases;

Comment: try that too, but it remain behind of the bootstrap modal. Tried index:100 but it still remains at the back of modal

Comment: @fypforstack look in your dev tools, you'll see that bootstrap modals have a z-index of 1050 by default, so unless you set yours higher than that, it will still be behind the modal

Comment: thanks that help a lot